# How are eigenvalues relevant to the invariants of a system?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For a matrix $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$, what can one say about its eigenvalues $\gamma_1, \gamma_2 \in \mathbb{C}$, if:

$$\mathbf{S}_0 \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$$

$$\mathbf{S}_{n+1} = \mathbf{A}\mathbf{S}_{n}$$

and for all $\mathbf{S}_i$ generated this way, the following holds: $\|\mathbf{S}_{i}\| = \|\mathbf{S}_{0}\|$.

That is, the Euclidean norm of $\mathbf{S}_0$ is preserved even under repeated action of $\mathbf{A}$.

Alternatively, what must the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}$ look like if the above holds true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the condition must be true for any eigenvector $v$ of eigenvalue $\gamma$, hence

$$|\gamma| . \| v \| = \| Av \| = \| v \| \ \ \Rightarrow |\gamma| = 1.$$

Comment: If both the eigenvalues are $1$, doesn't that just mean $\mathbf{A}$ has to be the identity matrix?

Comment: Yes. But the absolute values can be 1, without the eigenvalues being 1.

Comment: The eigenvalues are complex, even as the matrix is real. So in general, the pair of eigenvalues must be $e^{i\theta}$, $e^{-i\theta}$.